# How to access ErrorMessage attribute without using tag helper property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, razor-pages

How to access error message directly without using tag helper property? asp-validation-for add boilterplate code `class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"`.

View

```
<span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

PageModel

```
[BindProperty(Name = "password")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password must to minimun eight characters, one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and one spesial symbol")]
public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the error message like this?

```
 var errormessage = from state in this.ModelState.Values
                              from error in state.Errors
                              select error.ErrorMessage;
```

result:

[image]

**Or** Do you want like this?

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("password")
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

result:
[image]